# Do DOM events destroy after the element, they are bound to, dies?

Tags: javascript, events, dom

If I bind an event to a DOM element, does the event ever get destroyed if the element does? By destroying of an element I'm referring to removeChild(). A move of the node to another location with appendChild() leaves the event listener untouched.

Basically I'm interested in this because I want to know if I need to do some cleanup/tear down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean event **handler** here, right?  If so then it is a valid concern for garbage collection purposes to be careful with functions attached to elements via "onfoo" attributes.  IE has what amounts to separate garbage collectors for the DOM and for JavaScript, and they don't know much about each other.

I believe what suffices is to make sure that "onfoo" attributes are set to `null` when DOM elements are tossed aside. By so doing, the JavaScript code will have broken the reference to JavaScript memory allocated for the handlers, so the DOM garbage collector won't leak. Of course this goes for any other random attributes you may have added to DOM elements too.

Though I hate to suggest using a JavaScript framework for questions not so tagged, and in fact I won't actually make such a suggestion here, but I will say that one of the things frameworks (usually) do for you is try to keep the DOM "clean" in this kind of situation.

Comment: I am using jQuery mostly to bind event listeners, or just addEventListener. What's the case here? Do the listeners die along with their parents?

Comment: If you're using jQuery to bind your event handlers **and** to handle your DOM manipulations, then it should be handling that stuff for you.

Comment: So, you are saying that if I am using addEventListener(), I need to remove the listeners before removing DOM elements?